# How to preserve formatting in fish shell command substitution output stored in the var?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm already scratching my head for a while because of this:

```
> cat file
line1
line2
> set tst (cat file)
> echo "$tst" 
line1 line2
> set tst "(cat file)"
> echo "$tst"
(cat file)
```

In `bash` I can get it done like so:

```
$ cat file
line1
line2
$ tst=$(cat file)
$ echo "$tst"
line1
line2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, fish splits command substitutions (`(command)`) on newlines. To override that behavior, you can use the special [string](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html) subcommands like `string split` (which allows you to define what to split on), `string split0` (which splits on NUL bytes) and `string collect` (which doesn't split at all[0]).

So the answer is:

```
set tst (cat file | string collect)
echo $tst
```

[0]: Note that NUL bytes can't be passed to commands because unix passes the arguments as NUL-terminated strings, so there is no way for the command to know that the argument goes on, so `string collect` effectively just captures the command output up to the first NUL, giving you at most one entry, while `string split0` might result in multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

fish saves the result of a command substitution as a *list of lines* (except if `string collect` is used). So you can do

```
> set tst (cat file)
> printf '%s\n' $tst
line1
line2
```